# Partial Differential Equations Lagrange method

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lagrange-multiplier

In the following question:
$\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{dx}{y^2}$=$\frac{dz}{z(x+y)}$

I have to approach the solution in two different methods however both my answer conflicts.

Method 1:
Subtracting 1 and 2 and equating with 3rd

$x^{-2}dx$=$y^{-2}dy$

which gives on integrating:

$\frac{-1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$=$constant$

Method 2:

$\frac{zdx/x}{x}$=$\frac{zdy/y}{y}$=$\frac{dz}{x+y}$

now adding one and two subtracting from third

$\frac{dx}{x}$+$\frac{dy}{y}$=$\frac{dz}{z}$

which gives on integrating,

$xy/z=(constant)$

how ever both are different,in my book they subtract one and two then use the property $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$ to cancel it with x+y  which gives another constant however I think there are supposed to be only two solutions is there something wrong Iam doing please guide me through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usig $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$ we get the integral $\dfrac{x-y}{z}=c_3$. It says that the expression $\dfrac{x-y}{z}$ is constant along the characteristics.

You got two other expressions, $\dfrac{-1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{y}=c_1$ and $\dfrac{xy}{z}=c_2$, two constants along the characteristics. The point is that we can set $c_3$ from $c_1$ and $c_2$ alone:

$\dfrac{x-y}{xy}=c_1$ and $xy=zc_2$, then

$\dfrac{x-y}{zc_2}=c_1$ or $\dfrac{x-y}{z}=c_1c_2$

Meaning that $c_3=c_1c_2$. So, $c_3$ is not an independent constant. There are only two independent solutions.

Comment: Thank you I get it, Would also like to know that whether $f(c1,c2)$,$f(c2,c3)$,$f(c1,c3)$ are all the  valid solution of the partial differential equation given

Comment: All of them. Check them (e.g. $f\left(\dfrac{x-y}{z},\dfrac{x-y}{xy}\right)=0$) into the differential equation.

Comment: Thanks again could you please advice me how can I confirm my solution by substituting in equation,in other words where do I substitute my solutions

Comment: I supposed that system comes from some PDE. There is where you have to check the solution. By the way, maybe it makes simpler to check to write the general solution as $z=g\left(\dfrac{x-y}{xy}\right)(x-y)$

Comment: Yes I think we are supposed to substitute  in Pp+Qq=R where P=$\frac{d(U,V)}{d(y,z)}$ Q=$\frac{d(U,V)}{d(z,x)}$ and R=$\frac{d(U,V)}{d(x,y)}$ also p=$dz/dx$ q=$dz/dy$ also U=Solution 1 V=Solution 2 but doing so is quite difficult would be great if there is a way to cross check the answer

Comment: To make more suitable your inquiry to the forum format, I suggest you to make another question, this time referring to the way the pde's solutions are to be checked.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is a typo in your system of ODEs ($dx$ instead of $dy$) in the second fraction.

Sorry I cannot understand what you are doing because they are not enough steps edited when going from one equation to the next. Also you write "Subtracting 1 and 2 and equating with 3rd" without making clear what are 1, 2 and 3. If 1 is $\frac{dx}{x^2}$ and if 2 is $\frac{dy}{y^2}$ substracting gives $0$ since both are equal.

Moreover I don't understand why you are surprized because  "Method 1" and "Method 2" give different results. Fortunately they give different results ! Each one gives a characteristic equation wich are different one from the other.

A first characteristic equation is
$$\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x}=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation is
$$\frac{z}{xy}=c_2$$
I suppose that the PDE is
$$x^2\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y^2\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=(x+y)z$$
which leads to the Charpit-Lagrange system of ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{dy}{y^2}=\frac{dz}{(x+y)z}$$
Thanks to the two above characteristic equations one can get to the general solution of the PDE on implicit form $c_2=F(c_1)$ and on explicit form :
$$z(x,y)=xy\,F\left(\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
where $F$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to some conditions not given in the wording of the question).

VERIFICATION :

Let $\chi=\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x}\quad;\quad z(x,y)=xyF(\chi)\quad$ and with  symbol $\quad F'=\frac{dF}{d\chi}$.
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}= yF+xy\frac{\partial \chi}{\partial x}=yF+
\frac{y}{x}F'$$
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}= xF+xy\frac{\partial \chi}{\partial y}=xF-
\frac{x}{y}F'$$
$$x^2\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y^2\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=x^2\left(yF+\frac{y}{x}F'\right)+y^2\left(xF-\frac{x}{y}F'\right)$$
$$x^2\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y^2\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=x^2yF+y^2xF=(x+y)xyF$$
$$x^2\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y^2\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=(x+y)z$$
This is exactly the original PDE. Thus $z=xy\,F\left(\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is solution of the PDE.

Comment: By 1 and 2 in meant the first and second equality in the equation,actually in my second method subtracting 1 and 2 and equating with third does yield denominator as zero but since the equality exists I suppose it can be equated with third please correct if Iam wrong

Comment: You didn't wrote clearly what are the first, the second and the third equalities (three distinct equations in order to avoid ambiguity).